# spark-submit failing in cluster mode with error 13, permission denied for pyspark job

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera-cdh

We installed cloudera CDH 6.2 in RHEL 7 machine shipped with default python 2.7. Using python 3.7 in a virtual environment for spark-submitting pyspark jobs. Client mode with --master local and --deploy-mode client is working fine. But, having issues with --master yarn and --deploy-mode cluster.

This command **`spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/user/R1_I5/bin/python --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARK_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark --conf spark.executorEnv.SPARK_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark sample.py`** is failing with below 2 errors

**Case 1 Error log** :  --deploy-mode cluster

`Cannot run program "/home/user/R1_I5/bin/python": error=13, Permission denied` 
Detailed log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J7HLNGABnStJ91ISHFBMdNe5OLEUQZ6B/view

**Case 2 Error log** :  --master yarn

The below 2 lines are repeating without program getting terminated

```
INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1594339922772_0012 (state: ACCEPTED)
INFO yarn.SparkRackResolver: Got an error when resolving hostNames. Falling back to /default-rack for all
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to check permission on the directory  "hdfs://dwh:8020/user//.sparkStaging/application_1594339922772_0011" and see the user that you are running the program with, has access over it. the right way is to create an 'username' directory under 'hdfs://dwh:8020/user/username and run through it.
2. Check the hostnames of the master machine, the problem here is it is trying to connect to the master that is mentioned in the config but not able to find it.
   you can type. Go to Cloudera manager and user the option of redeploy config, also
   check the /etc/hosts and see if it matches with the hostnames mentioned in the Cloudera manager.

Comment: Hi @patel 1. i changed the ownership of the user folder in hdfs://dwh:8020/user/ to hdfs:supergroup with 777.  I could not find any application within .sparkstaging directory. After doing this, still, facing the errors mentioned in the question with spark-submit. 
2. checked the /etc/hosts. have correct hostnames there. Could you please mention if it is redeploy configuration or just deploy configuration in cloudera manager ? i see only deploy configuration. 
Thank you,

Comment: deploy configuration. 
Also create this directory for the user running the job for eg for user 'root' it would be  'hdfs://dwh:8020/user/root" 
for that  sudo su hdfs
hdfs dfs -mkdir  /user/root
 hdfs dfs -chown  root:root  /user/root

Comment: Hi patel, i deployed the config. Also, created root user and changed ownership as specified. Still getting permission denied at virtual environment R1_I5 as mentioned in case 1 Error log

Comment: Ok, Let me know if we can connect on zoom or something.

Comment: thank you. problem got solved. creating venv in a directory where i have permission restrictions led to the posted error. Changed the venv directory to /usr/local location and it worked with no issues in cluster mode too.